# visualize genres of movies

Tags: php, graph-visualization, vis.js

Using the example table below, I would like to show:

- a) nodes: that there are many movies that have "action" or "drama" as a genre
- b) edges (non-directional): when a movie has "drama" as a genre, that is is likely the movie also has the genre "action"

**My main question: how can I best create a list of all the edges consisting of all connected genres?**

Let's say I have a table with movies and genres:

```
GENRE       | MOVIE
--------------------------
Drama       | A
Action      | A
Comedy      | A

Documentary | B
Romantic    | B
Action      | B
Drama       | B

Drama       | C
Romantic    | C
Action      | C
---------------------------
```

I do not have a preference for visualization framework, but the following comes close to what I had in mind:
http://visjs.org/examples/network/09_sizing.html

**Other suggestions to visualize are more than welcome!**

Based on my movie example, the nodes and edges could look like:
http://jsfiddle.net/wivaku/90oef0pg/

[image: example of graph]

In this example the edges are hardcoded. In real life I would like to create them dynamically.
**How can I best create the edges JSON, preferably using PHP?**

The PHP snippet I have at the moment:

```
<?php
//the SQL rows (normally from SQL, now static):
$rows = json_decode('[["Drama","A"],["Action","A"],["Comedy","A"],["Documentary","B"],["Romantic","B"],["Action","B"],["Drama","B"],["Drama","C"],["Romantic","C"],["Action","C"]]');

$nodes = array();
$edges = array();

// create nodes
$genres = array_count_values(array_map(function($i) {return $i[0]; }, $rows));
foreach ($genres as $key => $value) {
    $nodes[] = array("id"=>$key, "value"=>$value);
}

// create edges
// helpful to have genres grouped by movie? (normally from SQL, now static)
$movieGenres = json_decode('[{"movie":"A","genres":["Drama","Action","Comedy"]},{"movie":"B","genres":["Documentary","Romantic","Action","Drama"]},{"movie":"C","genres":["Drama","Romantic","Action"]}]');
// ...

print json_encode(["nodes"=>$nodes, "edges"=>$edges], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**: regarding the comments about SQL details / options. The table I have is pretty much as listed. So: genreId and contentId.
One option I was exploring (as shortcut for the PHP code): concatenate the genres per movie.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(genreId SEPARATOR "|") AS genres
FROM contentGenres
GROUP BY contentId
ORDER BY count(genreId) DESC
```

With the example data:

```
Drama|Action|Comedy
Documentary|Romantic|Action|Drama
Drama|Romantic|Action
```

Or using the genre ID's:

```
1|2|3
4|5|2|1
1|5|2
```

The result of my real data set is ±11000 rows, with some movies having 8 genres.

Comment: is that a real table? if so then it needs normalization

Comment: no it is not a real table, just an example.

Comment: @Wivku: so you want to count the number of movies where two genres occur both to get the "strength" between two genres?

Comment: @CommuSoft yes, e.g. if the combination of Action-Drama appears in 3 movies, the "strength" is 3

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to do the processing at the database side? In general SQL is way better in these things... Can you provide the structure of your database?

Comment: @CommuSoft: yes, that's fine as well. The structure is pretty much as listed, two columns: contentId and genreId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the processing at the SQL level, for instance using this query:

```
SELECT a.genreId,b.genreId,count(*)
FROM genres as a, genres as b
WHERE a.contentId = b.contentId AND a.genreId < b.genreId
GROUP BY a.genreId, b.genreId
```

[see an online demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b62b8/2/0)

The id's are numbered as the genres in your example:

```
1 Drama
2 Action
3 Comedy
4 Documentary
5 Romantic
```

Comment: where are the bonus points? You didn't even upvote the answer :|

Comment: mmm, bonus points was figure of speech. :-0  Can these be handed out? Did not realize I should upvote in addition to marking the answer as accepted. Done.